# Filter for language when using graphQL

Tags: language, graphql

I try to use graphQL to get language specific entries from my Craft CMS. I (naively?) tried this:

```
query {
    entries (section: "newsIntranet", language: "fr") {
        title
        postDate
        expiryDate
        contentText
    }
}
```

because of this part of [doc](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#pre-defined-interfaces).
How can I get make sure that I only get entries of a given language when using graphQL from an extrernal system?

Comment: I tried using language too, and didn't seem to be able to make it work either.
Have you tried using `site` or `siteId` instead? That seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `siteId` for this.

```
query {
    entries (section: "newsIntranet", siteId: "2") {
        title
        postDate
        expiryDate
        contentText
    }
}
```

Swap out "2" with whatever the `siteId` of the French site is on your system.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick and helpful answer!